# Is there a browser that works well in extremely high latency (non-ideal) network situations?

Tags: windows, browser, internet

I have super high internet latency, from many seconds to many minutes.

It makes it impossible to browse the web, because all browsers I tried crash after some delay.

Is there any browser made for super high latency or an unreliable network?
I mean a browser which keeps trying to load the page even if the connection is temporarily lost?

Comment: Low latency = you get the response almost immediately. That's the opposite of what you're describing.

Comment: Voting to reopen this since while this does veer into software recommendations, I believe that the issue of haves/have-nots with regards to Internet speed is one that is not very well addressed. In many major regions, high-speed Internet is common, but not so much for other areas.

Comment: @JakeGould To be fair, I asked if a browser exists, not a recommendation for best software. I read the justification for not allowing software recommendations, and it says that is matter of opinion, and any answer would become obsolete. None apply to the question of if a software exists.

Comment: @zitryko - That is literally the definition of a question asking for a software recommendation.  Every answer to a question, asking for a software recommendation, would be for software that exists.  On those Stack Exchange communities where a software recommendation is allowed, an answer that indicates the software does not exist, would not be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any browser made for super high latency or an unreliable network?

There are a couple of mitigations you can try when browsing with low bandwidth or degraded [network QoS](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) situations.

[Opera Mini](//www.opera.com/es/mobile/mini/android) is built for unreliable networks. It has image modes and page modes specially designed to have cloud servers to crush pages into minimal blobs on your behalf and send them back to your phone. This has naturally big security risks, but can make your life easier when network is slow.

You might also want to use [TUI](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) based Internet browsers such as [Lynx](//lynx.invisible-island.net) or Links, for those will ignore [JS](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), so even though this obviously causes a huge interactivity impact, you are overall saving bandwidth, and the DOM theoretically should be there showing a static view of most meaningful information.

<sub>Best results are achieved when combining browsers made to save data with web sites made to make you save data. You might want to think twice about which services you use. For example, [Discord](//discordapp.com) consumes insane amounts of bandwidth. You might want to use [IRC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRC) instead, as a solid decentralized alternative. In that and many other cases, by using [Lynx](//lynx.invisible-island.net) you just simply get rid of the whole page, because it won't load without [JS](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to make Opera mini work with windows.

Comment: @zitryko I think regular Opera had a "mini toggle" at some point. I haven't used it in a while, but it may still be there.

Comment: I think Opera "regular" for desktop PCs has dropped the "mini" mode. But yeah I think it had some _easy_ "mini toggle" at some point.